# Match 2 files by first column, output column 2 of file 1 and column 2 and 3 of file 2

Tags: linux, csv, text, awk

I have 2 files.

File 1 has data as such:

```
def!:abcabc:abc123
sdf!:skdfkd:asd432
jkl!:kalsfs:kak323
```

File 2 has data as such:

```
def!:hi123
fjs!:aaaaa123
bab!:kfksfksasdf123
```

the output should be:

```
abcabc:abc123:hi123
```

I wrote the following one-liner which works fine however i'm using 2 arrays:

```
awk -F ':' -v OFS=':' 'FNR==NR{a[$1] = $0;f[$1] = $2;next} ($1 in a) {print $2,$3,f[$1]}' file2 file1 > output
```

Please give an explanation as to how the simplified version works.

Regards,

Andrew Smith

Comment: It seems you need to merge files. If so, try using `sort -m`

Comment: I am merging files however i only need specific columns. I have provided a solution to my problem however i feel there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: `sort` can merge specific columns only

Comment: Using gnu sort and gnu join: `join -t: -o 1.2,1.3,2.2  <( sort -t: file1 ) <( sort -t: file2 ) `

Comment: @LarsFischer, you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable with a solution using GNU sort and GNU join instead of awk, you can do it like this:

```
join -t: -o 1.2,1.3,2.2 <( sort -t: file1 ) <( sort -t: file2 )
```

This assumes that `file1` and `file2` are not sorted, thus the use of `sort`.

- the option `-t` is used to set the separator for `join` and `sort`
- the option `-o` of `join` select which parts of which file are used for the output, the info page of join (`info join`) has more information

Comment: I don't think this requires the GNU coreutils tools. It ought to work with standard tools too. Can you annotate the GNU-isms?

Comment: @Kusalananda No I cannot, I have only linux so test with and I am not sure about the options of `join` and `sort`.

Comment: since you're not sorting by other fields, separator is not necessary for the sort.

Answer (score 1):

THINK about what `a[]` is being used for in your script:

```
awk -F ':' -v OFS=':' 'FNR==NR{a[$1] = $0;f[$1] = $2;next} ($1 in a) {print $2,$3,f[$1]}' file2 file1 > output
```

You save `$0` in `a[$1]` so you are storing the entire contents of the first file in memory, but then you never do anything with the `$0` values you stored in `a[]`. All you do with `a[]` is test if `$1` is in it (`$1 in a`) but every time you do `a[$1]=$0` you also do `f[$1]=$2` so any time `$1 in a` is true, `$1 in f` must also be true and THAT's the array you actually use the contents of in your print statement. So you could get rid of `a[]` and just do:

```
awk -F ':' -v OFS=':' 'FNR==NR{f[$1] = $2;next} ($1 in f) {print $2,$3,f[$1]}' file2 file1 > output
```

and it'd work exactly as your original script. You don't need the parens around `$1 in f` and whenever you need 2 variables (e.g. `FS` and `OFS`) to have the same value it's best to set them together to that value instead of separately so your script could be written more idiomatically as:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} FNR==NR{f[$1]=$2;next} $1 in f{print $2,$3,f[$1]}' file2 file1 > output
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation !!

Comment: One more thing, when i do f[$1] = $2, is it not storing the second column of file2 into the array f? If so then how can the first array of file 1 be in array f? They are not the same columns. I'm confused on this..

Comment: Yes it is. I don't understand the question, sorry. I don't know what `the first array of file 1` means or what you mean by `They are not the same columns` - what do you mean by "`They"`?

Comment: I mean that if i'm storing column 2 of file 2 into array f then checking if column 1 of file 1 is in array f ($1 in f), Would that not give me no results since column 2 of file 2 and column 1 of file 1 have nothing in common?

Comment: Should it not be f[$1] = $1 ? But then if i do this i can't output column 2 of file 2 during the print command. This is what lead me to using 2 arrays in the first place.

Comment: The `in` operator works on array indices, not on the elements addressed by those indices. After you do `f[$1]="foo"` the condition `$1 in f` is true, not the condition `"foo" in f`. Column 1 of file1 and column 1 of file 2 have the values you want to compare. When you use the `in` operator you are treating the array as if it were a mathematical "set" - "does `$1` exist **in** the set of indices of array `f[]`?". Does that help clarify?

Comment: Yes that clarifies it a lot more. Thanks !

Comment: You're welcome. If/when someone posts a solution you decide to accept, remember to click on the check mark next to it to indicate you've accepted that answer.